# The \special macro in XeTeX

Tags: xetex

I was playing a bit with XeTeX and I was really surprised that the following was working

```
\def\red{\special{color rgb 1 0 0}}
{\red Hello, World!}
\bye
```

Where can I learn more about the syntax of what can be inserted in "special"?

Comment: You can look in the manuals for `dvipdfm` and `dvipdfmx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\special` primitive is a simple holder for 'material understood by the backend': TeX knows nothing of the nature of the argument here by design. As such, one has to check the documentation for the backend to know what is usable. Practically, it is often necessary to also carry out experiments on what works.

For XeTeX, the backend is `xdvipdfmx`, which is nowadays simply `dvipdfmx` running in the right mode. You need to look at the manuals for `dvipdfmx` and `dvipdfm`, and the document `dvipdfmx-special.pdf`, to get a good overview of what is usable.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction